# How do I create a displayed array of image thumbnails in a C# windows app?

Tags: c#, windows, image, thumbnails, picturebox

I want to create a displayed array of image thumbnails in a C# Windows app.

I would like each image to be selectable for migration into a picturebox.

Has anyone built something like this?

I am trying to figure the quickest/ most efficient way to do it. I have already considered a panel with a collection of images displayed therein.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the Image.GetThumbnailImage() to get a thumbnail of required images and place them in picturebox controls which will be created dynamically depending on the count of images to be displayed and then use the drag and drop to drag image from a tumbnail picturebox control to a panel for displaying the full size image etc.